# getName() returns null after upgrade to magento 1.9.38

Tags: magento

`getName()` returns `null` after upgrade to **magento 1.9.38**

in product page
the code i'm talking about is located in

> design/frontend/rwd/default/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/compsite.phtml

```
 <?php foreach ($this->getChildProducts() as $childProduct) : ?>
        <?php $childProductStockQty = $this->getProductStockQty($childProduct); ?>
        <?php if ($childProductStockQty > 0) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $childProduct->getName() ?></td>
                <td class="a-center"><?php echo $childProductStockQty ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

it's only showing the qty but not the product name. All this products are associated products to one configurable...

[the image where should appear the product name, on the product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ynLK.png)

Comment: try to debug using print_r($childProduct->getData());exit;

Comment: i've installed a new theme and it's working, this is strange behavior, because the theme files do not overwrite  the base theme rwd files...so with the theme  installed this $childProduct->getName() is showing data, with no theme nothing, i've tested the default magento rwd theme, at first i thought the problems was from my theme files...